# "Operation not permitted" while installing linux-headers-4.8.0-45

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm not sure how I came to this error, but whatever it was I am stuck now. I have run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

All of which were in different orders.

The error may have occurred while installing/removing skype.  Not skypeforlinux beta, but skype v4.XXX

```
dustin@dustin-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install -f  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
Correcting dependencies... Done  
The following additional packages will be installed:  
  linux-headers-4.8.0-45  
The following NEW packages will be installed:  
  linux-headers-4.8.0-45  
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.  
3 not fully installed or removed.  
Need to get 0 B/10.4 MB of archives.  
After this operation, 73.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y  
(Reading database ... 213275 files and directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.8.0-45_4.8.0-45.48~16.04.1_all.deb  ...  
Unpacking linux-headers-4.8.0-45 (4.8.0-45.48~16.04.1) ...  
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.8.0-45_4.8.0-45.48~16.04.1_all.deb (--unpack):  
 unable to open '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-45/arch/sh/include  /asm/addrspace.h.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted  
Errors were encountered while processing: 
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.8.0-45_4.8.0-45.48~16.04.1_all.deb  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)  
dustin@dustin-laptop:~$
```

Note that I am new to linux and everything it encompasses...
Usually I would just format the HDD and re-install, but I am getting tired of this procedure.
If more information is needed, just let me know and I'll put it on here if my status on this site allows it.

Comment: Adding to @Nathaniel's answer -- You can always create exception on Sophos Console. 
https://support.sophos.com/support/s/article/KB-000037190?language=en_US

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can see that you asked this question a long time ago, so it's probably not relevant to you any more, but I did run into this exact issue recently.  Were you by any chance running Sophos Antivirus?  That was preventing me from updating.  I was able to install everything by temporarily disabling Sophos Antivirus with `savdctl disable`, then I installed what I needed and then re-enabled `savdctl enable`.

Comment: I did have Sophos Antivirus installed and that is exactly what I did to get the update to go through.

Comment: Ooooooo thank you sooo much......I've tried so many different things and this was the actual issue!!!!!! My problem was with this package: `linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-23-generic_5.3.0-23.25_amd64.deb`. To enable disable Sophos: `sudo /opt/sophos-av/bin/savdctl disable / enable`

Comment: I got this error with linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-47-generic.  Same fix worked

Comment: I had the same issue on Proxmox (I know it's not Ubuntu). Temporarily disabling Sophos AV fixed it.

Comment: this fixed my issue with `linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-84-generic` when doing a `sudo apt upgrade` in ubuntu

Comment: You are a lifesaver. It solved a similar issue for me when installing linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when I had the same issue

```
apt autoremove -f
```