# `apt install gcc` fails because it cannot make a symlink in /lib

Tags: filesystem

I was trying to install GCC using apt, but it barked at me that it cannot create a link in `/lib`.

```bsh
update-alternatives: error: error creating symbolic 
link '/lib/cpp.dpkg-tmp': Operation not permitted
```

I started to investigate:

```bsh
root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal /lib # echo aaa > /lib/delme
-bash: /lib/delme: Operation not permitted
root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal /lib # ls -ld /lib
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 May 30  2019 /lib
root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal /lib # whoami
root
root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal /lib # df -h /lib
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2        437G  202G  213G  49% /
root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal /lib # lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal /lib # touch /lib/init/delme
```

Permissions seem OK, plenty of free space, and I can create files in `/lib/init` but not in `/lib`. This is an almost stock system nothing fancy except that I have LXD and Node.js installed. I did nothing to the filesystem, no partitioning, not  changing any permissions. What could be a problem?

Comment: A quick search via google says 'it could be the antivirus solution' (sophos in this case: https://askubuntu.com/questions/898606/operation-not-permitted-while-installing-linux-headers-4-8-0-45 ... or it could be a hiccup of apt, caused by a former issue, solved by: `apt autoremove -f`

Comment: @exebook - maybe you try it as sudo ? Then type : sudo apt install gcc