# Installing new kernel image - Unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.x.x.x-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted

Tags: package-management, kernel, updates, dpkg

All I did was run `apt upgrade` and the installation failed in upgrading to `linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic`. This is a dual boot system but as far as I can tell the file it's having a problem with resides on the regular system partition (mounted at /) and not the partition at `/boot/efi/`

Any hints or suggestions about what's going on or what other info I can provide would be most appreciated.

Apt output:

```
root@CSD-17459:~# apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-42 linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-hwe-5.8-source-5.8.0 linux-hwe-5.8-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
58 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,499 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,748 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 393849 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic_5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic (5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic_5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-34-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic_5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And here is the strace for the dpkg command and the file it's complaining about:

```
root@CSD-17459:~# strace -v -P /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-34-generic.dpkg-new dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic_5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2_amd64.deb 
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=6633, si_uid=0, si_status=1, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=6634, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
(Reading database ... 393849 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic_5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=6638, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
Unpacking linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic (5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2) ...
rmdir("/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-34-generic.dpkg-new") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-34-generic.dpkg-new", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 000) = 12
write(12, "MZ\352\7\0\300\7\214\310\216\330\216\300\216\3201\344\373\374\276@\0\254 \300t\t\264\16\273\7\0"..., 32768) = 32768
# ...
# many more binary blob write() calls here
# ....
sync_file_range(12, 0, 0, SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WRITE) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=6644, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
fchown(12, 0, 0)                        = 0
fchmod(12, 0600)                        = 0
close(12)                               = 0
utimes("/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-34-generic.dpkg-new", [{tv_sec=1609958683, tv_usec=0} /* 2021-01-06T12:44:43-0600 */, {tv_sec=1608216088, tv_usec=0} /* 2020-12-17T08:41:28-0600 */]) = 0

# ERROR HERE
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-34-generic.dpkg-new", O_WRONLY) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic_5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-34-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
rmdir("/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-34-generic.dpkg-new") = -1 ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
lstat("/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-34-generic.dpkg-new", {st_dev=makedev(0x103, 0x5), st_ino=787680, st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=18984, st_size=9716640, st_atime=1609958684 /* 2021-01-06T12:44:44.289897140-0600 */, st_atime_nsec=289897140, st_mtime=1608216088 /* 2020-12-17T08:41:28-0600 */, st_mtime_nsec=0, st_ctime=1609958684 /* 2021-01-06T12:44:44.285897140-0600 */, st_ctime_nsec=285897140}) = 0
unlink("/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-34-generic.dpkg-new") = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=6647, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=6656, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=6657, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic_5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2_amd64.deb
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: happen the same to me, I need to stop de antivirus first, then install que kernel update.
is like this other https://askubuntu.com/questions/898606/operation-not-permitted-while-installing-linux-headers-4-8-0-45

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that was it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was the anti-virus software that was blocking the package installation, as suggested by @khrysro. Temporarily deactivating the service allowed it to go through fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the **McAfee Agent** that was causing the issue.

I had to run the following commands below to uninstall it, as I did not have much need for it:

```
sudo dpkg --purge mfedx
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeetp
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeespaac
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeespfileaccess
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeesp
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeert
sudo dpkg --purge mfecma
sudo dpkg --purge mfert
```

I can also reinstall again by downloading the installer here:

https://ui-usw003.mvision.mcafee.com/ComputerMgmt/agentPackage.get?token=be9becf628d1c82d1af74f1496bd8aca87c26a2e

And then opening my terminal and then navigate to the folder when the installer was downloaded and then run the command below:

```
sh McAfeeSmartInstall.sh
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**