# unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg

I can't `apt upgrade` anymore after the dpkg broken installing linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic . I tried to remove the entries in /var/lib/dpkg/status . The /boot is not in a different partition. Thanks in advance. Information:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 : Depends: linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic but it is not installed
 linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-43-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic but it is not installed or
                                                 linux-image-unsigned-5.8.0-43-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

sudo apt --purge autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 : Depends: linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic but it is not installed
 linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-43-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic but it is not installed or
                                                 linux-image-unsigned-5.8.0-43-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-source-5.8.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10,7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 13,7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 494609 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic_5.8.0-43.49_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic (5.8.0-43.49) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic_5.8.0-43.49_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic_5.8.0-43.49_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ sudo df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           820M  2,2M  818M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2   83G   32G   47G  41% /
tmpfs           4,1G  376M  3,8G  10% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,3M  4,1k  5,3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4,2M     0  4,2M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p4  169G  9,3G  151G   6% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p1  207M  8,2M  199M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1       492G  175G  292G  38% /data
tmpfs           820M  156k  820M   1% /run/user/1000
overlay          83G   32G   47G  41% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/71bb1c050c92e223f622374cc46ba7ebffeb699f43fab7b291c7c774a2e366a4/merged

$ sudo ls -la /boot
total 146345
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 fev 10 08:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root     4096 jan 28 17:55 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   248258 jan 15 07:10 config-5.8.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   248258 jan 18 13:01 config-5.8.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   248258 fev  4 23:41 config-5.8.0-43-generic
drwx------  3 root root      512 dez 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 jan 27 20:06 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 jan 27 20:06 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.8.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 52092341 jan 26 15:02 initrd.img-5.8.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 52092440 jan 27 20:06 initrd.img-5.8.0-41-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 jan 26 15:04 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.8.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 ago 18 07:23 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 ago 18 07:23 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184884 ago 18 07:23 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  5635676 jan 15 07:10 System.map-5.8.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5635676 jan 18 13:01 System.map-5.8.0-41-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5635676 fev  4 23:41 System.map-5.8.0-43-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 jan 27 20:06 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-41-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 13715232 jan 15 07:20 vmlinuz-5.8.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 13715296 jan 18 13:08 vmlinuz-5.8.0-41-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 jan 26 15:04 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-40-generic
```

Comment: maybe helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305580/installing-new-kernel-image-dpkg-failing-with-permission-error-20-04

Comment: Thank you, @nobody , I'm trying this today.