# linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I was trying to install AnyDesk on my Ubuntu 20.04 and ran this command in the shell -

`abhilash@friday:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade`

And it returned:

```
   Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 9,822 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 385266 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic (5.8.0-53.60~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-53-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 8: /etc/default/grub: 2: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I saw this error message already addressed on the forum [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305580/installing-new-kernel-image-unable-to-open-boot-vmlinuz-5-x-x-x-generic-dpkg) but the discussion did not help me as I am running Ubuntu without dual-boot and don't have any antivirus softwares that might have caused the issue (according to the discussion on the question).

Since the package `linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic` looks associated with the os/kernel, I did not fiddle much with it but have already tried all the methods mentioned on https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/ but so far nothing has worked out.

I am currently able to access all of my data and able to reboot my system as well but would like to solve this problem as I am unable to install new packages.

Looking forward to any suggestions from the community.

Update: As pointed out by @user535733, I am sharing my /etc/default/grub file

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT= 10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: @user535733, thanks but looks like the file is present. I have shared it as an update in the question.

Comment: can you add `dpkg -l | grep grub-common` please to your question. And  `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`